# Android ListView Adapter getView is not working as expected

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have used this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) in order to create a custom listview, but for some reason it is behaving differently than what I expect.

Here is the code I changed and am currently using for the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     // same code as in example with some differences in the .xml
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setText(info.split(";")[0]);
    viewHolder.itemDescription.setText(info.split(";")[1]);
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setTag(position);
    if(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText().equals("Fat")){
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText());
        viewHolder.itemLabel.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.info_icon, 0);
    }
return convertView;
}
```

Now, what is happening is that for some reason the icon is being set for more than one item on the list even though there is only one with "Fat" on the label.
The print is actually showing that the code on the **if** is being run three times.

[image]

I think that this must have something to do with the lifecycle of the app, but i'm not sure about it.

I'm sorry if the question is to vague, but I couldn't find a better way to ask this.

Comment: Add the else  part to `if(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText().equals("Fat"))`. if running 3 times is OK . Usually `getView()` called several time on first creation of adapter .

Comment: Why do I need to add the else? There is no problem that the code is running 3 times, the only problem is that it is placing the icon on wrong textviews.

Comment: `placing the icon on wrong textviews`? Thats why you need else part to set it to default one . Read about role of `convertView` in `getView()`.

Comment: @GuiFGDeo can you please share screen short so We are solving easily.

Comment: I have added the screenshot, but I think that @ADM was right and I had to place the **else** loop with **viewHolder.itemLabel.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);**
Now it is working as intended

Comment: @ADM, please add your answer so I can accept it, and thank you! If possible add a quick note about convertView reusing the views and messing up everything :)

Comment: I think happen because of the recycle view behaviour. it use previouse created view and add as the new one. If you are not clearing the icon the icon in the recycled view will be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the else part inside `getView()`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // same code as in example with some differences in the .xml
    if(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText().equals("Fat")){
      // Stuff
    }else{
       // Else stuff
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

ConvertView parameter is a recycled instance of  View that you previously returned from `getView()`. You can read about it just search for it .
Making some quick points . You are not using viewholder pattern correctly in code. Use it properly look for ViewHolder pattern in List view. Apart from that you should Move to `RecyclerView` `ListView` is in legacy now.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try to move to RecyclerView later on, but it is too confusing for me right now. I never thought it would be so hard to create a simple custom list on Android.

Comment: Confusing ? Nope .. Try debugger . You will get the idea . debug each step to see whats going on exactly just for  One time !!! Or just search for topics what i have mentioned in answer .

Comment: No, I meant that RecyclerView is confusing hahaha... The example code from developer.android makes me a little confused. But i will try the debugger on my current code just to see how it does.

Answer (score 0):

Please check code It may be helpful.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     // same code as in example with some differences in the .xml
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setText(info.split(";")[0]);
    viewHolder.itemDescription.setText(info.split(";")[1]);
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.itemLabel.setTag(position);
    if(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText().equals("Fat")){
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println(viewHolder.itemLabel.getText());
        viewHolder.itemLabel.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.info_icon, 0);
    }else{
        viewHolder.itemLabel.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    }
    return convertView;
}
```